# Max Height and Max Width

Tags: html, css, image, resize, image-resizing

I have a set of images being displayed which cannot be bigger than 100px x 59px. I do however have a number of these images which scale smaller to around about 70px x 59px. For this I have this line of HTML to display the images:

```
<img src="image/image1.jpg " max-width="100px" max-height="59px" alt="Image1">
```

This does not however limit the constraints and are displaying the orginal size of the image regardless.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

use "style"

```
<img src="image/image1.jpg" style="max-width: 100px; max-height: 59px;" alt="Image1">
```

Answer (score 0):

rather than using max-height and max-width, use only height and width attribute. But it will eventually stretch your images in case they are of lesser size.

Comment: I don't want it to stretch you see!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `width: 100%;` and `height: 100%;` as well.